# Difference between Convert.ToBoolean(reader["Name"]) and (bool) (reader["Name"])?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysqldatareader

While working on a .Net project and `SqlDataReader`, came to question about difference between:

```
Convert.ToBoolean(reader["Name"])
```

And:

```
(bool) (reader["Name"])
```

Comment: The first will work if `Name` is a `string` with the value of `true`. The latter won't (it will only work if `Name` is actually a `bool`).

Comment: The first is called _Conversion_. The second is called _Casting_.

Comment: [`Convert.ToBoolean(/* a bunch of overloads, one accepts string, another object */)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.toboolean(v=vs.110).aspx).